# Ajax in Wordpress to reload a SELECT every second

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

My target is to take a page of an existent WP theme and customize a full width page, to make that every 1 seconds a MySQL SELECT query is reloaded and the results are shown.

Starting with [this](https://github.com/stafmans/stafmans.wiki.wordpress/wiki/6.3-AJAX-content-refresh-Wordpress) snippets I have made the following editing/new files:

1. template-fullwidth.php
2. functions.php
3. my.js (new file)
4. GetPostDate.php (new file)

**What I have done**

I started from the `template-fullwidth.php` of a theme and add the following code between the `DIV` of the post. The place where I wanted to show the results is between `<div id="MaxPostDate">` tags.

```
</div><!-- .post -->
<!-- START CUSTOM PAGE CODE -->
<?php
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // --- START IF USER LOGGED IN --- //
        // Get the current user name and id
?>
        <div id="MaxPostDate"></div>
        <?php      



    // --- END IF USER LOGGED IN --- //
    } else {
    // --- START IF USER NOT LOGGED IN --- //
    echo "<p>You have to log-in to see this content</p>";
    // --- END IF USER NOT LOGGED IN --- //
    } 
?>

                    <div class="result"></div>
<!-- END CUSTOM PAGE CODE -->
                    <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

                </div><!-- .posts -->
```

then I have edited the `functions.php` file of the theme adding this in the end:

```
function add_myjavascript(){
  wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-implementation.js', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . "/js/my.js", array( 'jquery' ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_myjavascript' );

function MyAjaxFunction(){
  //get the data from ajax() call

    $TableContent = $wpdb->get_results("
            SELECT MAX(`post_date`) AS MaxDate FROM wp_posts"
    );
    foreach($TableContent as $Content){echo "<h1>" . $Content->MaxDate . "</h1>";}

  // Return the String
   die($results);
  }
  // creating Ajax call for WordPress
   add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_MyAjaxFunction', 'MyAjaxFunction' );
   add_action( 'wp_ajax_MyAjaxFunction', 'MyAjaxFunction' );


?>
```

Then, I have made this `my.js` in the `js` folder of the theme:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function refresh_div() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:'/MySite/wp-content/themes/hemingway/GetPostDate.php',
            type:'POST',
            success:function(results) {
                jQuery(".result").html(results);
            }
        });
    }

    t = setInterval(refresh_div,1000););
```

And finally make another file GetPostDate.php

```
<?php
$TableContent = $wpdb->get_results("
            SELECT MAX(`post_date`) AS MaxDate FROM wp_posts"
    );
    foreach($TableContent as $Content){echo "<h1>" . $Content->MaxDate . "</h1>";

                                       ?>
```

**The problems**

- nothing appear inside the DIV id="MaxPostDate"
- I have wrote two time the same query (`SELECT MAX(`post_date`) AS MaxDate FROM wp_posts`), I would be wrote just one time!

Comment: You're doing it wrong: by sending your `GET` request to `/MySite/wp-content/themes/hemingway/GetPostDate.php` you're essentially bypassing the entire WordPress framework. Your `GetPostDate.php` script then doesn't have access to any of WordPress APIs/objects/functions so it won't do what you expect it to do. Actually, your error log is probably filled with PHP notices/warning/error messages due to that. Please review the documentation to learn [how to do AJAX requests the WordPress way](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this my.js in the js folder of the theme

```
jQuery(document).ready(function refresh_div() {
        jQuery.ajax({
           url:'//MySite/mysite/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            action:'MyAjaxFunction',
            type:'POST',
            dataType:json,
            success:function(results) {
                jQuery(".result").html(results.result);
            }
        });
    }

    t = setInterval(refresh_div,1000););
```

the functions.php file of the theme adding this in the end:

```
function MyAjaxFunction(){
  //get the data from ajax() call
    $jsonresult = array();
    $TableContent = $wpdb->get_results("
            SELECT MAX(`post_date`) AS MaxDate FROM wp_posts"
    );
    foreach($TableContent as $Content){
    $jsonresult['result'] = $Content->MaxDate

    }
    echo json_encode($jsonresult);
        die();

  }
  // creating Ajax call for WordPress
   add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_MyAjaxFunction', 'MyAjaxFunction' );
   add_action( 'wp_ajax_MyAjaxFunction', 'MyAjaxFunction' );
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is with your AJAX URL.

Execute your AJAX in footer.php like below:

```
 jQuery.ajax({
        url:'<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type:'POST',
        success:function(results) {
            jQuery(".result").html(results);
        }
    });
```

then you don't need GetPostDate.php file either.